# How to display xml in a bootstrap modal of mvc view

Tags: c#, angularjs, model-view-controller, bootstrap-5

How to load an xml file in same format in a bootstrap modal of mvc view.
i have tried as below but that doesn't look like the 1st screenshot i have attached but it looks like the second screenshot.

```
<pre lang="xml">
 (XML Content)
</pre>
```

[screenshot the expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9Kii.png)

[Screenshot which iam getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5Mih.png)

Comment: What does it look like? Posting the rendered HTML might be helpful.

Comment: @peter i have attached the screenshot of  response i'm getting in the post .. Thank you